# Checking status of storage operation in asynchronous MongoDb call

Tags: c#, mongodb, asynchronous

I have a method that updates a document in the DB.

```
public async Task<bool> UpdateThingAsync(Thing thing, CancellationToken token)
{
  Thing target = await Things.Find(x => x.Id == thing.Id)
    .SingleOrDefaultAsync(token);

  if (target == null)
    return false;

  await Things.FindOneAndReplaceAsync(x => x.Id == target.Id, thing, null, token);

  return true;
}
```

I'd like to verify that the storage has been successful and change the final returned boolean to be conditioned as follows.

```
public async Task<bool> UpdateThingAsync(Thing thing, CancellationToken token)
{
  Thing target = await Things.Find(x => x.Id == thing.Id)
    .SingleOrDefaultAsync(token);

  if (target == null)
    return false;

  Task<Thing> outcome = Things.FindOneAndReplaceAsync(x => x.Id == target.Id, thing, null, token);
  await outcome;

  return outcome.IsCompletedSuccessfully;
}
```

I've googled around but couldn't confirm that approach by finding simliar construction in any of the examples. That makes me worry that I'm missing something.

1. Does the above change assert the success of the storage operation?
2. Is there a smoother way to obtain the status than separate declaration and await?

Comment: Why even use `FindOneAndReplaceAsync` when you don't even care about the returned document? Why not use `ReplaceOneAsync`?

Comment: @Llama Excellent point. It might be due to my ignorance (new to Mongo) but the intention is to consider a case where the object is fetched first, merged with the replacement (there's a `Dictionary` there that may contain different keys) and stored with the combined set of properties. Feel free to criticize the approach in case I'm noob'ing up something.

Comment: I believe the only difference between `FindOneAndReplaceAsync` and `ReplaceOneAsync` is that the "find" one will retrieve the document before (or after, if you specify after as the return document via options). Beyond that, it simply replaces the existing one with the new one (i.e. `thing`) without doing anything smart.

Comment: One can also check the `Thing` of the `Task<Thing>` will be the updated / replaced document (with new values) - but must use the option `returnNewDocument: true` with the _replace_ method.

Comment: @Llama So you say it's better to *FindAsync(...)* the document, merge the data in the dictionary of properties and then *FindOneAndReplaceAsync(...)* the resulting instance?

Comment: @prasad_I didn't understand the suggestion. Would you, kindly please, reword it a bit. It's likely due to my noobness withing document DBs that I'm missing your point.

Comment: Call `FindAsync`, merge whatever you need to, call `ReplaceOneAsync`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking `IsCompletedSuccessfully` isn't going to work, because if the `Task` does not complete successfully, `await`ing it will unwrap and throw the exception:

```
await outcome; // Throws exception if unsuccessful

return outcome.IsCompletedSuccessfully; // Never evaluates if unsuccessful
```

It seems like, semantically, the `bool` return value is there to indicate whether a document has been updated based on whether it already exists or not; any MongoDb errors are *exeptional* and thus you should allow the exception to be unwrapped (as with your first example).

However, if you must return `false` in the case of a MongoDb exception, you could use this approach:

```
try
{
    await Things.FindOneAndReplaceAsync(x => x.Id == target.Id, thing, null, token);
    return true;
}
catch
{
    return false;
}
```